# How can I index all active sessions of a user in laravel and manage them?

Tags: laravel, laravel-session

I want to give users a capability to index his/her active sessions and terminate them on other devices. I am looking for something that is possible in messengers.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to a database session driver, you could get your results with a query.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#driver-prerequisites